# Is there an in-universe explanation for the difference between Orion males and females?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-eu

All the physical differences between the sexes of the (major) humanoid species of Star Trek are within a range that's known from humankind as well - except for the Orions. Whereas their females are grace personified, their male counterparts are downright orcish brutes. Is there any in-universe explanation for this huge difference in their appearance?

I'll be happy about explanations given by the TV show(s) as well as ones offered by novels or comic books.

Comment: Especially relevant given part of Star Trek's backstory has the humanoid races coming from a Preserver seeding, which is why so many of them are sexually compatible (and can, in many cases, interbreed).

Comment: You're assuming the individuals shown are typical of their species. If I did the same with humans I'd assume they're all physically fit and attractive.

Comment: @ BrianOrtiz Of course I do, since this seems to be the most sensible thing  to me. Particularly in a fictional setting, as long as I don't have further information, I carefully generalize the ones I have. This doesn't mean that there can't be any sick or weak Orions, but I do assume that all Orions are green-skinned and the VAST majority of women are highly attractive/seductive and radiate sensuality. There might be a freak  of nature or a small group of outcasts among them that for whatever don't live up to this expectation, but this wouldn't disprove my assumption -

Comment: quite the opposite, because their standing out would be a direct effect of not meeting the expectations connected to their species.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually female Orions are depicted as sensual and voluptuous, while males as strong  and muscular; I won't exactly use such terms as as "grace" and "brutishness" to describe them, and the sexes don't seem to have very different features: both of them are depicted with explicit carnal and sensual features and are very physically fit.

[image]
[image]

The strong sexual connotations of this race are tied to their physiology and society; quoting from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Orion):

> **Orion females were very animalistic in nature, known for their extreme carnal appetites and their innate skill of seduction**. A
>   Human male could rarely resist the alluring dance of the Orion slave
>   girl.
>
> In Orion society, the males were slaves to the females. As a means of
>   deceiving other species, the Orions maintained the facade that the
>   females were the slaves. This went as far as Orion females on the
>   Orion slave market.
>
> Once sold to a male, **the Orion slave girls used their unique
>   physiology to their advantage; their highly potent pheromones
>   accelerated the metabolisms of males of many species**, raising
>   adrenaline production to dangerous levels which caused aggression and,
>   ultimately, a form of delusion. Its most significant effect was to
>   make them susceptible to suggestion. Not long after, the "owner" males
>   began taking orders from their "slave" females. **The pheromones'
>   effects were cumulative; the longer exposed, the more pronounced the
>   results.**
>
> Human females reacted negatively to those same pheromones,
>   experiencing headaches, and Denobulan males found their sleep cycles
>   interrupted by them. Vulcans were immune to effects of the pheromones.
>
> In 2155, Dr. Phlox of Enterprise NX-01 theorized that the pheromone
>   acted as a defense mechanism against competition.

The strong feminine features and pheromones of the females seem to produce an accelerated production of hormones even in their males counterpart, giving as a result a race with pronounced gender-defining features and a strong connotations of sex both in their physiology and their society (as we already knew).

Comment: The similarity in terms of 'explicit carnal and sensual features' is an interesting point you raise; I haven't seen it from that angle. Before watching Enterprise, I imagined the males to be Errol Flynn-like characters, so I was quite... surprised when I saw my first male Orion, who resembled Grishnakh more than any protagonist of a 50's pirates flick.

Answer (score 1):

No real in-universe explanation, but Discovery and Lower Decks started showing male Orions who weren't brutish-looking.

Comment: You could illustrate the point better by adding relevant images (and preferably naming the episodes the images are from).

Comment: As you note this doesn't really explain why the difference.